# Completing a Debian installation

Tags: debian, networking, aptitude

Here's what I did:

I installed Debian by burning the first ISO from the repository to a USB. Booted from it, got Debian installed - except no desktop.

I tried using aptitude to get it, but I need a CD. So I installed my network adapter drivers (netgear wna1100, installed via usb as per Google of wna1100 Linux drivers) and tried to connect to the internet. Drivers seemingly installed fine with no errors, my network adapter is correctly identified in lsusb, but any command to connect to the internet relied on wlan0 which doesn't appear to exist. Nor does iwconfig...

How can I get a compete installation?

Comment: Using http://linuxcommando.blogspot.lu/2013/10/how-to-connect-to-wpawpa2-wifi-network.html as a guideline, please refine the data given about the exact circumstances and the errors encountered. Start with `iw dev` output.

Comment: Also, are you installing Debian Jessie or some other version? E.g., were you to be installing testing (Stretch), the device naming has changed, so it'd not be 'wlan0'

Comment: @derobert To my knowledge I am installing Jessie (8.2) or the stable version

Comment: @Alex Stragies /sbin/iw dev produces no output, but no 'unknown command' message either. Tried variations like just 'iw dev' to the same end.

Comment: Empty `iw dev` output means your driver is not loaded, you have the wrong driver, or need firmware installed/copied. Or device broken- It works on windows?. Please post relevant line from `lsusb` and `lsmod`. http://askubuntu.com/questions/216066/installing-driver-for-netgear-wna1100-wifi-adapter-ubuntu-server-12-04 may help. I think you need to install the `firmware-atheros` package.

Comment: It works on Windows. **lsusb**: Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0846:9030 NetGear, Inc. WNA1100 Wireless-N 150 [Atheros AR9271] **lsmod** can't find a relevant line because for some reason I can't scroll up. Just installed atheros via USB, and iw dev is still empty. I installed both files from that question a while ago.

Comment: I have something! Restarting gave iw Dev some output and I have brought my device up. Now I just need help connecting to mY network.